# Form border style set to none but title bar still present

Tags: vb.net

[image: image of problem]

I set the borderstyle of my form to none but this title bar still appears and i have no idea what this belongs to

[image: image 2]

This is when i set my border style so that it is visible

Comment: Is this an MDI child form, by any chance?

Comment: it is a parent form but the child form causes the title bar to appear on top of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the ControlBox of the form to false, like this:

```
Me.ControlBox = False
```

Comment: that solved it at first , but when i hide and show the MDI child form, it appears again